# Should the >= and <= operators be used on integers?

Tags: language-agnostic, operators

Is it considered better practice when comparing integer values to use the pattern:

```
if(i > n - 1)
```

or

```
if(i >= n)
```

In my experience with C, C++, and Python the former case seems to be more heavily used.  Is there a reason why the >= and <= operators customarily avoided with integers?

Comment: Never knew that, seems I must change my code. But FYI, you can substitute `a > b` for `!(a <= b)` on integers.

Comment: @Deduplicator - are you serious?

Comment: @CraigAnderson: Why?

Comment: @Deduplicator - you are going to change your code to avoid >= and <=?

Comment: @Deduplicator I wouldn't advise changing anything.  I just think its odd that I see > and < used far more frequently in cases where <= and >= would be more compact.

Comment: @CraigAnderson: Don't you know mindlessly running with the herd is fun?

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm still learning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `>=` avoids the possibility of (n-1) wrapping around to a large positive value if one is dealing with unsigned integers, so I would find that preferable.

Comment: In the cases I had in mind the values of i should typically be and unsigned index.  That said, I am guilty of usually using int rather than uint types.  Really we should all be using size_t for indexing variables but usually don't.

Comment: I'd like to add to this by saying that, if you're sure wrap-around isn't going to be an issue, always try to write your code so that it shows your intention. For example, if you want to check whether the number of apples in a bucket is greater than 5 after one has been eaten, write if ( 5 > numApples - 1 ) as opposed to if ( 5 >= numApples ).